# Unit Testing a GPS detecting method

Tags: java, unit-testing, android-studio, junit, junit4

I really need help with unit testing a method. I simply don't really understand how to go about it. This method is called when pressing a navigation button that centers on your location on my android app. Let's call it buttnav.

```
public void GPSDetector() { 
    AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            mapFragment.getActivity());
    build
            .setTitle("GPS Detection Services")
            .setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Enable it?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Enable GPS",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });
    build.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = build.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Map fragment being an entity instantiated as a SupportMapFragment on onActivityCreated inside of a fragment as such:

```
mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

I'm pretty lost and couldn't find much documentation referring to unit testing within Android core functionality. I'm trying to use Junit. I tried espresso but it doesn't encompass Android core functionality views.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  - UnitTests test the *public observable behavior* of a unit *in isolation* You must refactor your code to enable the latter.

Comment: I don't see how I can refactor the code in such a way. Do you have documentation somewhere or a really good website?

Comment: I can recoment readings: "Clean Code" by *Robert C. Martin* and "Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests" by *Steve Freeman / Nat Pryce*

Comment: Consider reading one of the many many tutorials about unit testing first. The code as written right is now is **hard** to test.

Answer (score 0):

at first: get used to [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Method names start with a lower case letter and preferably with a *verb*.

---

In order to verify the behavior of this method you buts replace the instance of `AlertDialog.Builder` with a *test double*. You should use a *mocking Framework* like *Mockito* to create one. Then you must refactor your code so that is provides a *seam* at which you can replace the real dependency with the test double.

> Some might sugest *PowerMock(-ito)* but I for myself concider the user of it as a surrendeer to bad design.

Whitout knowing the rest of your code my suggestion is to pass in the `AlertDialog.Builder` instance as a parameter to your method.